# How to create line between react native elements (view/touchableopacity/button) to draw family tree

Tags: react-native, tree, react-native-svg, family-tree

I'm trying to develop React Native mobile app to draw a family tree
[image: Family Tree Screen]

Any suggestion on how to draw line between the family member to create the tree, the element is touchableopacity.
I have try using react-native-svg, but I cannot get the screen coordinate of the touchableopacity.

here's the code

```
class FamilyTreeScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userId: '',
            isLoading: false,
            memberData: null,
            parentData: null,
            childData: null,
            siblingData: null,
            name: '',
            city: '',
            memberId: 0,
            age: 0
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getMemberData();
    }

    handleLoading = boolean => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: boolean })
    }

    async handleRTO(){
        Alert.alert('Connection Problem','Check your internet connection and try again.');
    }

    async fetchAccountData(){
        if (this.props.navigation.state.params)
            await this.setState({
                userId: this.props.navigation.getParam('memberId', 0),
            });
        else
            await this.setState({
                userId: Number(await AsyncStorage.getItem('userId')),
            });
        // console.log(this.state.userId);
    }

    async getMemberData(){
        await this.fetchAccountData();
        
        this.handleLoading(true);
        var req = await fetch(base_url + 'Relationship/get_relationship/' + this.state.userId, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHTTPREQUEST',
            },
        })
        .then(function(response){
            // console.log(response);
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(parsedJson){
            // console.log('get trah: '+JSON.stringify(parsedJson));
            if (parsedJson.status){
                return parsedJson.data;
            }
            else{
                return null;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.handleRTO();
            console.error(error);
        });
    
        if (req){
            await this.setState({
                memberData: req.member,
                parentData: req.parent,
                childData: req.child,
                siblingData: req.sibling
            });
        }
        this.handleLoading(false);
    }

    renderMember(){
        if (this.state.memberData)
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ 
                        name: this.state.memberData[0].first_name + " " + this.state.memberData[0].middle_name + " " + this.state.memberData[0].last_name,
                        city: this.state.memberData[0].city,
                        memberId: this.state.memberData[0].member_id,
                        age: this.state.memberData[0].umur,
                    })}>
                    <View style={defaultStyles.familyTreeProfile}>
                        <Image source={this.state.memberData[0].pp ? {uri: member_img_path + this.state.memberData[0].pp} : pp_home} style={defaultStyles.familyTreePhoto} />
                        <Text style={[textStyles.regular14, colorStyles.blackText, defaultStyles.familyTreeText]}>{this.state.memberData[0].first_name} {this.state.memberData[0].middle_name} {this.state.memberData[0].last_name}</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        else
            return null;
    }

    renderParent(){
        var memberList = [];
        if (this.state.parentData){
            this.state.parentData.map((item, idx) => {
                memberList.push(
                    // <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('PublicProfile', {
                    //     memberId: item.parent_id
                    // })}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ 
                            name: item.first_name + " " + item.middle_name + " " + item.last_name,
                            city: item.city,
                            memberId: item.parent_id,
                            age: item.umur
                        })}>
                        <View style={defaultStyles.familyTreeProfile}
                          ref={(ref) => { this.marker = ref }}
                          onLayout={({nativeEvent}) => {
                              console.log("render parent");
                            if (this.marker) {
                              this.marker.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
                                        console.log(x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY);
                               })
                            }
                          }}>
                            <Image source={item.pp ? {uri: member_img_path + item.pp} : pp_home} style={defaultStyles.familyTreePhoto} />
                            <Text style={[textStyles.regular14, colorStyles.blackText]}>{item.first_name} {item.middle_name} {item.last_name}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                );
            });
        }
        return memberList;
    }

    renderSibling(){
        var memberList = [];
        if (this.state.siblingData){
            this.state.siblingData.map((item, idx) => {
                memberList.push(
                    // <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('PublicProfile', {
                    //     memberId: item.person_id
                    // })}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ 
                        name: item.first_name + " " + item.middle_name + " " + item.last_name,
                        city: item.city,
                        memberId: item.person_id,
                        age: item.umur
                    })}>
                        <View style={defaultStyles.familyTreeProfile}>
                            <Image source={item.pp ? {uri: member_img_path + item.pp} : pp_home} style={defaultStyles.familyTreePhoto} />
                            <Text style={[textStyles.regular14, colorStyles.blackText]}>{item.first_name} {item.middle_name} {item.last_name}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                );
            });
        }
        return memberList;
    }

    renderChild(){
        var memberList = [];
        if (this.state.childData){
            this.state.childData.map((item, idx) => {
                memberList.push(
                    // <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('PublicProfile', {
                    //     memberId: item.person_id
                    // })}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ 
                        name: item.first_name + " " + item.middle_name + " " + item.last_name,
                        city: item.city,
                        memberId: item.person_id,
                        age: item.umur
                    })}>
                        <View style={defaultStyles.familyTreeProfile}>
                            <Image source={item.pp ? {uri: member_img_path + item.pp} : pp_home} style={defaultStyles.familyTreePhoto} />
                            <Text style={[textStyles.regular14, colorStyles.blackText]}>{item.first_name} {item.middle_name} {item.last_name}</Text>
                                
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                );
            });
        }
        return memberList;
    }

    renderUmur(){
        if (this.state.memberId)
            return (
                <Text>{this.state.age} old</Text>
            );
        else
            return null;
    }

    renderButton(){
        if (this.state.memberId)
            return (
                <View style={defaultStyles.btnContainer2}>
                    <Button style={[defaultStyles.trahMembershipButton]} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('PublicProfile', {
                        memberId: this.state.memberId
                    })}>
                        <Icon
                            active
                            type="FontAwesome"
                            name="user"
                            style={[{fontSize: 25}, colorStyles.blackText]}
                        />
                    </Button>
                    <Text> </Text>
                    <Button style={[defaultStyles.trahMembershipButton]} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('FamilyTree', {
                        memberId: this.state.memberId
                    })}>
                        <Image source={familytree_navbar} style={defaultStyles.trahMembershipImage} />
                    </Button>
                </View>
            );
        else
            return null;
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading){
            return (
                <View style={defaultStyles.loading}>
                    <ActivityIndicator
                        size="large"
                    />
                </View>
            );
        }
        else{
            return (
                <Container style={[defaultStyles.container, colorStyles.bg]}>
                    <Header style={[colorStyles.yellow, defaultStyles.registerHeader]}>
                        <Left>
                            <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                                <Icon
                                    type="FontAwesome"
                                    name="angle-left" 
                                    style={[colorStyles.blackText]}
                                />
                            </Button>
                        </Left>
                        <Body style={defaultStyles.headerContent}>
                            <Title style={[colorStyles.blackText, textStyles.bold18]}>FAMILY TREE</Title>
                        </Body>
                    </Header>
                    <Content contentContainerStyle={defaultStyles.contentContainer}>
                        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}} horizontal={true}>
                            <PinchZoomView>
                                <View style={defaultStyles.familyTreeContainer}>
                                    {this.renderParent()}
                                </View>
                                <View style={defaultStyles.familyTreeContainer}
                      ref={(ref) => { this.marker = ref }}
                      onLayout={({nativeEvent}) => {
                        console.log("render member");
                        if (this.marker) {
                          this.marker.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
                                    console.log(x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY);
                           })
                        }
                      }}>
                                    {this.renderMember()}
                                    {this.renderSibling()}
                                </View>
                                <View style={defaultStyles.familyTreeContainer}>
                                    {this.renderChild()}
                                </View>
                            </PinchZoomView>
                        </ScrollView>
                        <View style={defaultStyles.bottom}>
                            <Text>{this.state.name}</Text>
                            <Text>{this.state.city}</Text>
                            {this.renderUmur()}
                            {this.renderButton()}
                        </View>
                    </Content>
                    {Navbar(this.props.navigation, 'familytree')}
                </Container>
            );
        }
    }
}
export default FamilyTreeScreen;
```

If you have any suggestion, please let me know, Thank you

Comment: I think you need to use `react-native-svg` for you purpose. You can check out this package [https://github.com/Johncy1997/react-native-family-tree](https://github.com/Johncy1997/react-native-family-tree).

Comment: you could just use a view with height 1 (depending on the thickness) and width variable for a horizontal line and width 1 an height variable for a vertical one.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is just a line, you can easily achieve it by using the css below. Just give it to your component which needs to have line;

```
line: {
      borderBottomWidth: 1, // it can be border left or border right width
      borderColor: "#0000", // or any color,
      borderWidth: 120, // Should be number. 120 is just an example
    },
```